# Rails views behaving awkward

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am showing index of certain table say donations on Rails and after the table Rails is showing some kind of = debug or = inspect of the @donations when there are no debug or inspect methods anywhere in the code.

**views/bpm_steps/_donation_record.html.haml**

```
= donations.each do |d|
  %li
    %table
      %tr
        %td
          - if controller_name != "users"
```

Comment: We need more information. Maybe you can paste the view code? and the controller code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line of your `_donation_record.html.haml` file, you shouldn't be using `=`, otherwise this will output the contents of `donations` after executing the loop. Use a dash instead:

```
- donations.each do |d|
```